# Can we verify a mobile number without sending a text message?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to verify a mobile number without the help of message sending and verification code. By checking whether the number is online or not. I could not find any way to check whether the number is active in the network. Is it possible to determine if a particular number is active on the network or not?

Comment: What are the reasons you don't wish to use a mobile number? If it's the cost, you could look at purchasing a Skype international SMS package and use an API to send the SMS via Skype

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no other reliable way to verify that a mobile number belongs to some person without sending a verification code to this mobile number and then asking the person to enter this verification code on your website.

Comment: The question makes it sound like it's only necessary that the number is online, and not who it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give a call to the number.In an effort to protect your users from abuse, it is  sometimes better to ask users to prove they’re not a robot before they're able to create or sign in to accounts. Having this additional confirmation **via phone** is an effective way to keep spammers from abusing your systems.

If you want to do this in code <kbd>C#</kbd>, then there is no other way to check this.